# web.py databasing with inner join queries

Tags: python, mysql, sql, object, web.py

I am using web.py and have the following database call.

```
results = db.query("""SELECT users.EMAIL, credentials.STATUS
                       FROM users
                       INNER JOIN credentials
                       ON users.ACCOUNT_ID = credentials.ACCOUNT_ID
                       WHERE credentials.API_KEY=%s""" % api_key)
```

When I am trying to access the results I am getting all sorts of errors:

```
>> for i in results:
>>        print i
>> print results[0]['EMAIL']
>> print results[0]['STATUS']
IndexError: already passed 0
```

If I remove the print statements I get the following:

```
Storage {'STATUS': u'ACTIVE', 'EMAIL': u'testuser@gmail.com'}
```

but I can no way access `results` as a dictionary.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of the `db.query` method behaves like sequence, but it's basically iterator. (To be exact, it's [`web.utils.IterBetter` object](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/7b63e2e6b74bfd25a9bc6f1188caa74cfb0eafd9/web/utils.py#L630))

Iterator in Python normally cannot go backward.

Do something with the row while you iterate it.

```
for row in results:
    print row['EMAIL']
    print row['STATUS']
```

or make results as sequence to random access it:

```
results = list(results)
print results[0]['EMAIL']
print results[0]['STATUS']
```